# Iterating through a list of string lists?

Tags: python, string, list, int

I'm new to Python, coming from C; this is my first post, I looked all over for help on how to solve my problem but I cannot find it anywhere unfortunately.

I have a list of lists, and within the lists are strings of numbers(sorting dates):

```
    d = [['2012', '11', '14'], ['2012', '11', '13'], ['2012', '11', '12']]
```

I am trying to convert these string numbers into integers but i'm not sure how to do it using the way i had used for a normal string list, which was

```
    int_list = [int(x) for x in str_list]
```

How do i iterate through my list of lists and convert the string numbers into integers so that my list looks like this instead

```
    d = [[2012, 11, 14], [2012, 11, 13], [2012, 11, 12]]
```

Sorry if this question has been asked before but I could really use some help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use list comprehension:

```
>>> d = [['2012', '11', '14'], ['2012', '11', '13'], ['2012', '11', '12']]
>>> i = [[int(x) for x in l] for l in d]
>>> i
[[2012, 11, 14], [2012, 11, 13], [2012, 11, 12]]
```

i think your problem was that it is a nested list so iterating (int(x)) through `d` is trying to convert lists into ints

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! 
It seems easy to understand now but coming from C i'm still a little confused haha thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` with list comprehension.

```
d=[map(int,i) for i in d]
```

For python 3.x, use:

```
d=[list(map(int,i)) for i in d]
```

Comment: I tried this and I got:
`d = [<map object at 0x047E2BD0>, <map object at 0x047E2C10>...]`

Comment: Thank you for this solution! should have specified that i was using python 3 in my post haha

Answer (score 1):

A nested list comprehension works nicely:

```
d = [[int(x) for x in sublist] for sublist in d]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I had seen comprehensions on other posts when I was looking for a solution but didn't understand how to access each specific element using for.. thanks for the answer!